# Issue while getting values from table row in react

Tags: reactjs, react-table, primereact

I am using the prime react table where that values are getting show in table but then prime react table is not iterating the values from anywhere
But i need to get each id value from the table

Below is my code

```
<DataTable ref={dt} value={rows} selection={selectedProducts} onSelectionChange={(e) => {setEmployeeId(e.value)}} 
dataKey="id" paginator rows={10} currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords} products"
globalFilter={globalFilter} responsiveLayout="scroll">
<Column selectionMode="multiple" headerStyle={{ width: '2rem' }} exportable={false}></Column>
<Column header="Action" body={actionBodyTemplate} exportable={false} style={{ minWidth: '2rem' }}></Column>
<Column field="name" header='Name' sortable style={{ minWidth: '2rem' }}></Column>
<Column field="workingTime" header='Working Time' sortable style={{ minWidth: '2rem' }}></Column>                    
</DataTable>
```

Here i want the each rows name after click on the table row

Comment: Can you show your code running on an online editor like codesandbox?

Comment: I have not added it into the codesandbox because that class contains more components, but i have referring the below url for the prime react table please check   https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/datatable/crud/